# Compiling OpenCV on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, opencv, compilation, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to get OpenCV working on Windows 7 64bit.

I tried installing the vs2008.exe installer bundle from the OpenCV website but it produced errors when trying to compile, I Google'd these and it appears that installer is no good for 64bit versions of Windows 7, bugger.

I've tried having a crack at compiling using CMake, but really having no luck, does anyone know of a way to get OpenCV installed on here so I can use it in VS2010?

Cheers

Comment: what kind of "no luck" did you have with CMake?

Comment: Ah sorry, I managed to get it to use VS2010 to configure, then I hit 'Generate' and it instantly did something, but I couldn't find where it had generated anything - is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: for the sake of completeness (though I know you've already solved you problem) - yes, there *is* something else to do. `generate` has only created a project specific for your building environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it, in the 'release' folder which CMake creates I was opening the wrong file with VS2010, I opened the project file and then had it run a build.

Then I changed the parameters in my project which wanted to use OpenCV to look in `release` for the appropriate files, needed a bit of fiddling but I think I have it now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested in a guide how to compile OpenCV with TBB support in Visual Studio 2010, I created a video tutorial for it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBhwbRoKvk
(although this is for Windows 7 32 bit)

Comment: For anyone interested on doing it on Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2012, you can find this [blog post](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/) pretty helpful.